# Running Projects in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I've got a project from my teacher, in which i should add my implementation for a certain aspect.

The Project already got a `main` method but still the **"Run"** and **"Debug"** buttons in the top right corner are greyed out.

I've also tried right clicking the main method and java file, but it doesnt show me run or debug.

Also tried using the "Make Project" Button (top right corner), but it doesnt let me run it either.

How can i run the project?

Help would be much appreciated cause I cant seem to find a solution...

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

Comment: @Defozo yeah i kinda tried that too, but if i want to select the main class (in which my main method is located) i cant press ok because its greyed out ...

Comment: Does it compile?  Does it register the code you've had in the folder as actual source code (is the folder your code under blue)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "run" and "debug"-button in the top run the currently selected `main`-method. As long as you haven't selected one, you can't run it. In the current version on the left side of the editor-pane, there should be a green arrow right next to the `main`-button. Run it once via clicking that arrow and from that point on you can run/debug the program using the buttons on the top-window.

[image]

In this image you can see the green arrows (version 2016.2.4).

Alternatively, you can use the following more complicated, but also more versatile option:
Directly from the run- and debug-buttons is a button that toggles a list. In the initial configuration of the project, this list contains exactly one Item: "Edit Configurations...". Use it to create a custom-target - go for Application, if your using a java-class as entry-point - and set up the configuration as you wish. Clicking the arrow mentioned earlier does basically the same with a bit of automatic configuration.

Third alternative:
Open the context-menu on the `main`-method. It as well contains options to run and debug the program with the marked method as entry-point. Works for the context-menu of the respective class as well.

Comment: cant seem to find anything on the left side of the editor pane right next to the main method

Comment: @user343037 I've edited the answer with a screenshot showing the arrows. If you haven't got them you're using a pretty outdated version. The arrows have been around since I think nearly a year. I've added a third option to run the program.

Comment: @school_guy I'm not OP. I can't accept your answer.

Comment: sry did not scroll enough

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a run configuration. Do this with clicking the grey button and then clicking at sth with configurations (i am not in front of my PC), then add there the config

Comment: there are several other simpler possibilities, though this one works as well

Answer (score 0):

Does your main method have the proper syntax for arguments? I found that in Eclipse, the program will not let you run the main method if it is not in the format of `public static void main(String[] args)`. Also, does your code compile properly and your IDE just doesn't let you run it?